# On Spring, how to query DynamoDB table using JPA and a composite key (Partition Key and Sort Key)?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Spring project set up with JPA and Spring Data DynamoDB. It works alright. I can obtain items from the DynamoDB table by reading it by Partition Key and the Sort key (referred as `DynamoDBHashKey` and `DynamoDBRangeKey`).

My problem is that the way my repository is set up, the table is being read using `query` and `scan` operations, instead of `get-item` operation, which should be more efficient.

This is my entity:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "my-entity-table")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @DynamoDBHashKey 
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "partition_key")
    private String partitionKey;

    @Id
    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "sort_key")
    private String sortKey;

    ...
}
```

And this is my repository:

```
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.EnableScan;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@EnableScan
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String> {
    List<MyEntity> findByPartitionKeyAndSortKey(String partitionKey, String sortKey);
}
```

How do I configure my entity and repository to read items from the table using the `get-item` operation when my table has both a Partition Key and Sort Key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having done some research I stumbled onto this two articles:

1. [Composite Primary Keys Kotlin Example](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Composite-Primary-Keys-Kotlin-Example)
2. [Spring Data JPA with a Hash & Range Key DynamoDB Table](http://johnhunsley.blogspot.com/2016/11/spring-data-jpa-with-hash-range-key.html)

The first one explains how to do what I want in Kotlin. Not bad, but it is not exactly what I'm looking for.

The second one hits the target perfectly, basically what it says is that I need to create a Primary Key object for my entity object, like this:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBDocument;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBIgnore;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBRangeKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "my-entity-table")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @DynamoDBIgnore
    private PrimaryKey primaryKey;

    ...

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "partition_key")
    public String getPartitionKey() {
        return primaryKey != null ? primaryKey.getPartitionKey() : null;
    }

    public void setPartitionKey(final String partitionKey) {
        if (primaryKey == null) {
            primaryKey = new PrimaryKey();
        }
        primaryKey.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "sort_key")
    public String getSortKey() {
        return primaryKey != null ? primaryKey.getSortKey() : null;
    }

    public void setSortKey(final String sortKey) {
        if (primaryKey == null) {
            primaryKey = new PrimaryKey();
        }
        primaryKey.setSortKey(sortKey);
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @DynamoDBDocument
    public static class PrimaryKey {
        @DynamoDBHashKey 
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "partition_key")
        private String partitionKey;

        @DynamoDBRangeKey
        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "sort_key")
        private String sortKey;
    }
}
```

Then, I don't need to create any custom query methods on my repository class:

```
@EnableScan
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends 
        CrudRepository<MyEntity, MyEntity.PrimaryKey> {

}
```

And after that, it is just matter of using JPA's `CrudRepository` methods to obtain the items, like this:

```
final MyEntity.PrimaryKey myEntityPK 
    = new MyEntity.PrimaryKey("partitionKey", "sortKey");

final MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findById(myEntityPK)
    .orElseThrow(() -> ... );
```

To verify that it actually is using the `get-item` operation instead of the `scan` and `query` operations, one could place a couple of breakpoints on the following classes (as of `spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0`):

- `org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.core.DynamoDBTemplate`
- `org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository`