# Why ReflectionEntityInformation when using Composite key of DynamoDB in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am learning DynamoDb, so was trying to do a basic project using Spring Boot and DynamoDB. I checked these link to run this application successfully, but got failed :(

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57386532/2952011
2. http://johnhunsley.blogspot.com/2016/11/spring-data-jpa-with-hash-range-key.html
3. https://medium.com/@leohoc/dynamodb-and-spring-data-a81c546a1305

For db setup, I used docker. Here is my compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: localstack
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - USE_SSL=0
      - AWS_CBOR_DISABLE=1
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOSTNAME=localstack
      - SERVICES=dynamodb
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    ports:
      - '4566-4583:4566-4583'
    volumes:
      - ${TEMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/var/lib/localstack
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./script/init-dynamodb.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/init-dynamodb.sh
```

The script to create tables is here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# -- > Create DynamoDb Table
echo Creating  DynamoDb \'ItemInfo\' table ...
echo $(awslocal dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json '{
    "TableName":"ItemInfo",
    "KeySchema":
      [
        {"AttributeName":"id","KeyType":"HASH"}
      ],
      "AttributeDefinitions":
        [
          {"AttributeName":"id","AttributeType":"S"}
        ],
        "BillingMode":"PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  }'
)

echo Creating  DynamoDb \'Music\' table ...

echo $(awslocal dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json '{
    "TableName":"Music",
    "KeySchema":
      [
        {"AttributeName":"Artist","KeyType":"HASH"},
        {"AttributeName":"SongTitle","KeyType":"RANGE"}
      ],
      "AttributeDefinitions":
        [
          {"AttributeName":"Artist","AttributeType":"S"},
          {"AttributeName":"SongTitle","AttributeType":"S"}
        ],
      "ProvisionedThroughput":{
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 5,
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 5
      },
      "TableClass": "STANDARD"
  }'
)

# --> List DynamoDb Tables
echo Listing tables ...
echo $(awslocal dynamodb list-tables)
```

So after running:

```
sudo docker compose up -d
```

when I execute this:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 --region=us-east-1  dynamodb describe-table --table-name Music
```

I am getting this:

```
{
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "Artist",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "SongTitle",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "Music",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "Artist",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "SongTitle",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "CreationDateTime": "2023-03-07T14:17:46.287000+06:00",
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "LastIncreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T06:00:00+06:00",
            "LastDecreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T06:00:00+06:00",
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 0,
        "ItemCount": 0,
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:000000000000:table/Music",
        "TableId": "bcce1ab3-8f0c-4b8f-9d55-6c69ec1ef2ad",
        "Replicas": [],
        "TableClassSummary": {
            "TableClass": "STANDARD"
        }
    }
}
```

So I believe table creation is okay. Now I am showing the (DynamoDB Table) Music class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Music")
public class Music implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private MusicId musicId;

    public Music() {}

    public Music(MusicId musicId) {
        this.musicId = musicId;
    }

    public MusicId getMusicId() {
        return musicId;
    }

    public void setMusicId(MusicId musicId) {
        this.musicId = musicId;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Artist")
    public String getArtist() {
        return musicId != null ? musicId.getArtist() : null;
    }
    
    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        if (musicId == null)
            musicId = new MusicId();
        musicId.setArtist(artist);
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "SongTitle")
    public String getSongTitle() {
        return musicId != null ? musicId.getSongTitle() : null;
    }

    public void setSongTitle(String songTitle) {
        if (musicId == null)
            musicId = new MusicId();
        musicId.setSongTitle(songTitle);
    }
}
```

Here is MusicId (DynamoDB Document) class:

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class MusicId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;

    public MusicId() {

    }

    public MusicId(String artist, String songTitle) {
        this.artist = artist;
        this.songTitle = songTitle;
    }

    private String artist;
    private String songTitle;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Artist")
    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "SongTitle")
    public String getSongTitle() {
        return songTitle;
    }

    public void setSongTitle(String songTitle) {
        this.songTitle = songTitle;
    }
}
```

Here is MusicRepository:

```
@EnableScan
public interface MusicRepository extends CrudRepository<Music, MusicId> {
}
```

Here is DynamoDbServiceImpl which implements DynamoDbService:

```
@Service
public class DynamoDbServiceImpl implements DynamoDbService {
    private final ItemInfoRepository itemInfoRepository;
    private final MusicRepository musicRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DynamoDbServiceImpl(ItemInfoRepository itemInfoRepository, MusicRepository musicRepository) {
        this.itemInfoRepository = itemInfoRepository;
        this.musicRepository = musicRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveItem(ItemInfoDto dto) {
        ItemInfo itemInfo = new ItemInfo();
        itemInfo.setItemName(dto.getItemName());
        itemInfo.setItemUrl(dto.getItemUrl());
        itemInfoRepository.save(itemInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveMusic(MusicDto dto) {
        Music music = new Music();
        music.setArtist(dto.getArtist());
        musicRepository.save(music);
    }
}
```

And here is the AwsDynamoDbConfig to configure:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "com.mukit09.dynamodblearning.repository")
public class AwsDynamoDbConfig {
    @Value("${config.aws.region}")
    private String region;
    @Value("${config.aws.dynamodb.url}")
    private String dynamoDbEndpointUrl;
    @Value("${config.aws.dynamodb.access-key}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${config.aws.dynamodb.secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Bean(name = "amazonDynamoDB")
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(getCredentialsProvider())
                .withEndpointConfiguration(getEndpointConfiguration(dynamoDbEndpointUrl))
                .build();
    }

    private EndpointConfiguration getEndpointConfiguration(String url) {
        return new EndpointConfiguration(url, region);
    }

    private AWSStaticCredentialsProvider getCredentialsProvider() {
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(getBasicAWSCredentials());
    }

    private BasicAWSCredentials getBasicAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    }
}
```

These are the contents from application.properties:

```
#dynamoDB
config.aws.region=us-east-1
config.aws.dynamodb.url=http://127.0.0.1:4566
config.aws.dynamodb.access-key=localstack
config.aws.dynamodb.secret-key=localstack

#log
logging.file.name=debug.log
logging.level.root= debug
```

This is my gradle file (build.gradle):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.9'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.mukit09'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.github.derjust:spring-data-dynamodb:5.1.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.12.420'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I try to run this application, it is failed keeping this log:

```
2023-03-07 17:32:17.375 ERROR 68881 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDbController' defined in file [/home/mukit09/code/java/dynamodb-learning/build/classes/java/main/com/mukit09/dynamodblearning/controller/DynamoDbController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDbServiceImpl' defined in file [/home/mukit09/code/java/dynamodb-learning/build/classes/java/main/com/mukit09/dynamodblearning/service/impl/DynamoDbServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'musicRepository' defined in com.mukit09.dynamodblearning.repository.MusicRepository defined in @EnableDynamoDBRepositories declared on AwsDynamoDbConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/ReflectionEntityInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at com.mukit09.dynamodblearning.DynamodbLearningApplication.main(DynamodbLearningApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDbServiceImpl' defined in file [/home/mukit09/code/java/dynamodb-learning/build/classes/java/main/com/mukit09/dynamodblearning/service/impl/DynamoDbServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'musicRepository' defined in com.mukit09.dynamodblearning.repository.MusicRepository defined in @EnableDynamoDBRepositories declared on AwsDynamoDbConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/ReflectionEntityInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'musicRepository' defined in com.mukit09.dynamodblearning.repository.MusicRepository defined in @EnableDynamoDBRepositories declared on AwsDynamoDbConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/ReflectionEntityInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/ReflectionEntityInformation
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.getEntityInformation(DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.java:125) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:104) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getDynamoDBRepository(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:128) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:150) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:325) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ReflectionEntityInformation
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 64 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

As a learner of this stack, definitely I did some mistake. Would you please help me please to find the error I made please?

Comment: Seems like some dependency is missing. Can you try adding `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency and see if this solves?

Comment: It works for single Primary key, with the same dependency. But when I use composite key then it got failed :( But I am trying

Comment: @KaranSharma I guess, it shouldn't be, as after adding that, I am getting this now:
The bean 'itemInfoRepository', defined in com.mukit09.dynamodblearning.repository.ItemInfoRepository defined in EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in com.mukit09.dynamodblearning.repository.ItemInfoRepository defined in EnableDynamoDBRepositories declared on AwsDynamoDbConfig and overriding is disabled.

Comment: so it will have two repositories then to enable: EnableJpaRepositories and EnableDynamoDBRepositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, as you can find [here](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/issues/279) and [here](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/issues/267) as Spring > 2.2 is not supported.

There is a fork for which it may work, but I have not tested:

https://github.com/boostchicken/spring-data-dynamodb.

Comment: You are great, man! I just wonder, why Spring Boot don't have any embedded dependency yet for dynamodb? The spring boot projects who use dynamodb, will have to use a vulnerable dependency if they want to use the latest spring boot versions :(

Comment: just one thing:  2.2  itself isn't supported